# MySQL: - Bulk insert category to all posts in wordpress

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I am searching for a MySQL query that via PHPmyAdmin inserts a category (Not modify existing) to all existing posts. Bulk edit in Wordpress dashboard doesn't work for me because of high server load, I have more than 2000 posts and I need to add an another category "Italy" to all of them and do not remove existing categories (italian cities). Can anyone help?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

I've found some useful information for your problem:

**wp_categories**

If you have any categories in your WordPress installation, wp_categories is the table that keeps those records. Category names and descriptions are stored here, as well the ID of each category’s parent.

To work faster, WordPress often keeps aggregated values in the database, instead of recalculating them each time. For example, frequently requested counts of posts and links in each category are simply stored in the wp_categories table (WordPress uses the same set of categories for both links and posts). Every time you add post to a category, the post counter (column category_counter) increases. Every time you remove post from the category, the counter decreased. Same goes for links (column link_count). That’s why you see those extra columns in the table.

**wp_post2cat**

Linking posts to categories is done via wp_post2cat table. This is a standard approach for many-to-many relationships in relational databases. Thewp_post2cat table has only three fields: the unique record ID (automatically generated), the ID of the post, and the ID of the category to add the post to.

So if you could just give us 1 table row of the "wp_categories" we could easily create a query for bulk actions.

source: http://wpbits.wordpress.com/2007/08/08/a-look-inside-the-wordpress-database/

cheers.